# Partial views on rails not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started working with partials on rails making use of **<%=render "Name_of_the_view"%>** inside HTML files but for some reason the partial view is not displayed.

The partial is found but not rendered so all I get is the h1 title from the main view.

Already checked spelling, settings and all that kind of stuff but no clue what is wrong.

Here it is the code:

Main HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>Create article</h1>

   <%= render "form" %>
</div>
```

**_form** file that contains the partial view I want to render (It´s inside the same folder where the main HTML file is):

```
<%= form_for @article do |f|%>

      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
         <div class="card-panel red">
            <span class="white-text"><%= message %></span>
         </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="title" class="active">Title</label>
         <%=f.text_field :title, class:"form-control"%>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="body" class="active">Body</label>
         <%=f.text_area :body, class:"form-control", style:"height:250px"%>
      </div>
         <%=f.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn btn-primary"%>
   </div>
<%end%>
```

This is the controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @articles = Article.all
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title,:body)
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you generate a new scaffold by using the rails command

```
rails g scaffold YourScaffolds mystring:string
```

If you check the path

```
yourscaffolds/new
```

can you see the rendered form or not? If this is a general problem I cannot help you. If you can see the partial for a standard scaffold than there must be something wrong in your code.

Unless you get an error message from RoR your partial is usually found. The above code looks just fine. You need to make sure however that the partial is in the same folder as your view template.

so for you it could be

/articles/new.html.erb
/articles/_form.html.erb

Make sure your file where you call `<%= render "form" %>` has the .erb extension. Good luck!

Can you post your controller method? Are you using default scaffold?
Can you see the content of the template and only the partial is missing?

The syntax as as follows:

```
render "products/show"

render template: "products/show"
```

make sure you have the ruby identifiers wrapped around this. 
    <%= %>
Than there should be absolutely no reason why the partial is not rendering. Check your code for any spelling mistake. a partial should always start with under score _

Comment: That´s the problem. Everything is as you said: both files are in the same folder and both have the same .erb extension and all I get it´s a blank section.

Comment: Added additional info about the problem.